# Removing whitespaces caused by separate source files

Tags: spacing, sectioning, include

I have an article which consists of multiple files, a main file with following section includes:

```
\include{Introduction}
\include{ProposedProtocol}
\include{Comparison}
\include{FutureWork}
\include{References}
```

But there is a problem when I see the output. There are extra white spaces at the beginning of every section. A minimal start of the section files looks like this:

```
%!TEX root = Main.tex

\section{Proposed Protocol}
Content of the section goes here
```

Is there any way to remove these white spaces and make every section start where the previous one ends?

Comment: `\include` always does a `\clearpage`; use `\input`

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Would you please state your solution as an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\include` command always does a `\clearpage`, which is necessary to keep cross references in synch when the file is not really included (via `\includeonly`).

Changing `\include` into a simple `\input` cures the problem.

A comment. With modern machines, `\include` has only limited usefulness, since compilation is fast enough that the old way with `\includeonly` does not spare much time. Anyway, `\include` is best used for entire chapters, that will issue `\clearpage` also by themselves.