# pageskip when loading text from external file

Tags: page-breaking, revtex

I have the following MWE, using REVTeX:

```
\documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
    \title{Title} 
    \author{Dog} 
    \date{\today}

    \begin{abstract}
        \include{abstract}
    \end{abstract} 

    \maketitle

    \include{text}

\end{document}
```

When I use `\include`, then the page is skipped before inserted text. When I just write the directly without using `\include`, then the text is placed there as expected, without any `\newpage`.

Why is that?

Comment: `\include` always does `\clearpage`. Use `\input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\include` instruction is made for big chunks of text so as to allow compilation without really inputting the files; it's mostly useful during preparation of large documents.

In order to work properly, it *must* issue a `\clearpage` command. So it's not really useful for your problem.

```
\documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
    \title{Title} 
    \author{Dog} 
    \date{\today}

    \begin{abstract}
        \input{abstract}
    \end{abstract} 

    \maketitle

    \input{text}

\end{document}
```

should be the preferred form.

See [Redefining \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/redefining-include), [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files), or [Removing whitespaces caused by separate source files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/removing-whitespaces-caused-by-separate-source-files) for more information